# overloading operator puzzle: return *this, or temporary variable?

Tags: c++

if I overloading the + operator, I can use this(assume the class is className)

```
 className operator+(className & c) { // version 1
    className T;
    ...
    return T;
}
```

also I can use

```
className operator+(className & c) {   // version 2
    ....
    return *this;
}
```

here's my question:

1. in version 2, I return referfence or just like that? why?
2. version 1 and version 2, which one is better ?
3. we often write overloading =, << return by reference, to use the chain =/<< , but why without reference we can't use chain =/<<, what's the copy thing really mean?
4. another question is that, I saw in effective c++: "use const whenever possible" and "prefer use pass by reference" , Is that mean that I write class function declaration use const and reference as much as possible?

if I write like this:

```
template<typename T> 
void Print(const T data[], const int & arraySize)  // i use the const, and &
{ 
   for(inti = 0; i < arraySize; ++i) 
   cout << data[i] << " "; 
   cout << endl; 
}
```

when I write in main() function,I write:

```
int iArray[14] = {7,3,32,2,55,34,6,13,29,22,11,9,1,5}; 
int numInts = 14;    // do I need to specify numInts is const??
```

Print(iArray, numInts);

Answer (score 1):

> in version 2, I return referfence or just like that? why?

Doesn't matter, it's wrong.

> version 1 and version 2, which one is better ?

Version 1. The second one modifies the `this` object, so writing `x + y` would modify `x`, which doesn't make sense.

> we often write overloading =, << return by reference, to use the chain =/<< , but why without reference we can't use chain =/<<, what's the copy thing really mean?

Without the reference, you're just returning a copy - a temp - so chaining wouldn't make sense in those situations. Writing a chained `=` would apply the call to a different object, not the one `=` was called on.

> another question is that, I saw in <>: "use const whenever possible" and "prefer use pass by reference" , Is that mean that I write class function declaration use const and reference as much as possible?

Not really. Use them when it makes sense. For example, it makes sense for your `operator +` to be `const` because you shouldn't modify the arguments. This would also give a compiler error for version 2 (which is good).

As for pass by reference - it should be preferred for large objects - for an `int` or `float` - pass by value if you're not modifying it inside.

Comment: why my version 2 is wrong? I think it's right. I modify the *this, like x += c.x, and return  *this, what's worng?

Comment: @user1760040 in `x += c.x`, you expect `x` to be modified. Modifying `this` for simple `+` means that if you do `z = x + y`, `x` will be modified. Is that what you want?

Comment: @user1760040 Your question doesn't talk about `+=` but about `+`, two totally different operators.